# DateSerial Not Outputting Expected Date

Tags: vba

I have a bit of VBA code that uses `DateSerial`, but it is not outputting the suspected results. I was hoping for a bit of an explanation as to why, as I was not expecting the results at all.

My code looks like this:

```
 Set rngTestDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Range("A:A").Find(DateSerial(Year(TheDate1), 1, 1))
```

And the output looks like this:

```
?rngTestDate
11/1/2016 
?Year(TheDate1)
2016 
?DateSerial(Year(TheDate1),1,1)
1/1/2016
```

Using the immediate window, `Sheet11` does not have January 1, 2016 in it; however, it does have January 4, 2016 and also November 1, 2016. I was fully expecting the `.Find` method to look for 1/1/2016 and if it wasn't found, to be set to `Nothing`. If it didn't do that, at least find the next available date.
Why does the `.Find` method find November 1, 2016 over January 4, 2016 when it is given the above `DateSerial` value? Or I guess the better question is: if 1/1/2016 is not found, why does it not set to `Nothing`?

Comment: you are looking for `1/1/2016`, and `11/1/2016` contains it (starting at the second character).

Comment: Oh wow... So even though I'm using `DateSerial`, it's still looking for the closest thing containing the value of "1/1/2016", regardless of if the date is an exact match or not? It's almost like `.Find` is treating the `DateSerial` output like a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Vincent G's comment, the issue was that I was searching for `"1/1/2016"` and `"11/1/2016"` contained that string. It seems to be treating the date as a string, regardless of the `DateSerial` option. Was able to resolve the issue once I fully understood it. Thank you, Vincent G!